# Problems with leaderboard using the facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to make a leaderboard using the facebook unity sdk(for android devices in my case) I have most of the code down and it works just fine in the editor and on phone.
I can post my score as well as retrieve it in the editor using my access token.
I can also post and retrieve my score on an android where I logged in with my id.(the one to which the app is connected)

**But here's the problem:** 
When I try logging in with another account I can neither post my score nor can I retrieve it.
though I can get the username, profile pic of the account with which I am logged in as No.1 but the score remains 0.
Even the score of my other account isn't visible in the leaderboard.

What I deduced:
As it's mentioned on the Scores API page you require the publish_actions permission to post scores I believe this is what I am missing. But this does not explain why I am unable to see my score posted from my (developer) account.
Is it that during testing with an access token or on a mobile device using the developer or administrator account I can only see my own score using the "AppID/scores?fields=scores"?

```
void SetScore()
{
        score = //score
        var ScoreData =  new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"score", score.ToString()}};
        FB.API("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, publishActionCallback, ScoreData);
        Debug.Log ("Score data" + ScoreData);
}


void publishActionCallback(FBResult result){ Debug.Log ("ScoreUpdated!");}

public void friendsScore()
{
    FB.API("/MYAPPID/scores?fields=score", 
           Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, CallbackFriendScores);
    //HTTP GET request for the scores
}
CallbackFriendScore(FBResult result){Debug.Log ("response GET: " +result.Text);//the real callback is different but the debug can be used to recreate the same problem}
```

Note: I am trying to use FB.API("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, publishActionCallback, ScoreData)
and FB.API("/MYAPPID/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, CallbackFriendScores) to get the scores.

Comment: We need to see some code before we can help!

Comment: Adding code, just a minute.

Comment: I was missing the user_friends permission in the login.